# SQL entries in French/English and Japanese

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, character-encoding

I have an old SQL4 database and I'm trying to re-upload it to our newly created database on Phpmyadmin. The characters in the tables are latin and japanese. I tried to change those specific columns but the result is still broken characters for the columns I need to display in Japanese.

Here is a screenshot of my problem : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSaW8.jpg

As an example, the SQL code looks like this :

```
CREATE TABLE `bdd` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ville` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nom_fr` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nom_jp` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET sjis NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `adr_fr` text NOT NULL,
  `adr_jp` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET sjis NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `plan` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `bdd` (`id`, `ville`, `nom_fr`, `nom_jp`, `adr_fr`, `adr_jp`, `tel`, `plan`) VALUES
(47, 'Tokyo', 'THE KNOT TOKYO Shinjuku', '?U ?m?b?g ?????V?h', '4-31-1 Nishi Shinjuku, Shinjuku Ku, Tokyo', '?????s?V?h???V?h4-31-1', '03-3375-6511', 'the knot.JPG'),
(3546, 'Tokyo', 'HOSHINOYA Tokyo', '???????', '1-9-1 Otemachi, Chiyoda-ku, Tokyo 100-0004', '??100-0004 ?????s?????c??????????9??1', '0570-073-066', 'HOSHINOYA TOKYO.JPG'),
```

Comment: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php%2Fcharcoll%23diagnosing_charset_issues%2F

Comment: The question marks represented _already damaged_ encoding.  You need to get back to before the data was damaged.  Can you get hex out of the source dataset?

Comment: It seems like damage is already done indeed. Here is the original source SQL file : https://codeshare.io/5wV6Wp It wasn't damaged at that moment, only after I changed the file to unicode when I reimported the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.
I didn't try to change encoding any longer but created a new table with all rows in utf8mb4_unicode_ci and imported the data within this new table.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SET NAMES "utf8";
CREATE TABLE `bdd` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ville` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nom_fr` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `nom_jp` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET sjis NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `adr_fr` text NOT NULL,
  `adr_jp` varchar(3000) CHARACTER SET sjis NOT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `plan` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT whatever you want
```

It would be better if you stored everything in utf8 as you have multiple langueages. And before insertion you neeed to set your connection parameters accordingly so server can understand what you're sending. Btw maybe you'll have to 
`SET NAMES 'sjis';`

Comment: I re-uploaded the database. I have all my columns in utf8_general_ci and the two Japanese colums with sjis_japanese_ci. yet it still display with that kind of text "?U ?m?b?g ?????V?h". Should I add `SET NAMES 'sjis';` somewhere? How to limit this to only these two columns? Thank you.

Comment: @DestinationJapon - How was the data dumped?

Comment: `SET NAMES 'sjis';` is the command you execure _before_ any other SQL command. And btw really check the data you're inserting cause the sample you gave for me contains only question marks not japan symbols

Comment: On the unchanged SQL file I extracted from the old database I got symbols like `'ã–ìƒTƒbƒgƒ“ƒvƒŒƒCƒXƒzƒeƒ‹'` so maybe something went wrong when changing to Unicode. This old file is in ANSI. I changed `/*!40101 SET NAMES latin1 */;` to `SET NAMES "utf8";` and set Japanese for some columns because it was not set. Old file : `  `nom_jp` varchar(250) NOT NULL default '',` New file : `  `nom_jp` varchar(250) CHARACTER SET sjis NOT NULL DEFAULT '',` The only other thing I changed is this `TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3688 ;`to this `ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3688 ;`